# What are the best practices for starting a script where only one instance exists in python

Tags: python, sockets, subprocess

I have a loop A that I want to run, which reads in data from a directory D and does stuff. A edits files and handles communication to another object, and I want to avoid difficulties with synchronization. I want to be able to call A through a script B.py that loads data into D, and starts A if A isn't running.

**Ideally I'd like to be able to know if the starting of A failed or not and have that print to the console that tried to start it** (which I don't know how to do), while also having this done is the "safest" and with good python practices. I also would want to know if there is a way to listen into A somehow through the socket.

The way I have been thinking of implementing this is as follows:
A.py is a file that includes A. A.py first connects to a socket, and if it doesn't work then we might know according to an exit code (?)

```
import time
import socket
import sys
import os

DEFAULT_PORT = 9563

try:
  # Building manager lock to prevent another instance from running
  lock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  lock.bind(("localhost", DEFAULT_PORT))
except OSError:
  print("A is already running")
  sys.exit(3)

filename = "log.txt"
dirname = "D"
for i in range(30):
  with open(filename, "a", encoding="utf8") as f:
    num_files = len(os.listdir(dirname))
    f.write(f"idx: {i}, {time.asctime()}, {num_files} files found\n")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Then in B, we can put files into directory D, and call A with subprocess Popen. Because A checks a default port, it can only have one instance.

```
import os
import sys
import platform
import time
import subprocess


dirname = "D"
# Putting data into our directory
filename = str(time.time())
with open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), mode="w", encoding="utf8") as f:
  f.write("a file")

kwargs = {}
if platform.system() == "Windows":
  CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP = 0x00000200
  DETATCHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
  kwargs.update(creationflags=DETATCHED_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
else:
  kwargs.update(satart_new_session=True)

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "A.py"],
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, **kwargs)
assert not p.poll()
print("Goodbye")
sys.exit(0)
```

So I just wanted to ask if this is the pythonic way to do this. I have heard that opening a subprocess is an antipattern, but I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

This works and does what I expect. I'm just wondering if this is how it's best done.

EDIT:

**In short, I want manage a number of experiments that belong to different people. Experiments take a variable amount of time to run, and information will be printed out to a console to manage it. The equipment management needs to be set up in a way where two individual experiments cannot overwrite the other's commands. I also need it so that ending one experiment doesn't affect the management of another experiment.**

I work in a biology lab and we have a piece of equipment that our computer interfaces with. This equipment can have commands that overwrite old commands, and I can't touch this code. I need our lab computer to figure out logic according to configuration files for each experiment it is managing, and package them into instructions, repeating instructions if there has been no change in them.

We used to have code that would remember old instructions per experiment, and just resend them if those instructions weren't executed (an overwrite happened). I've since rewritten that work for a cleaner implementation, but I want to be able to, with a single command, copy configuration files into a folder for A to look through, but also to start A if it hasn't been started yet. I also want this to be cross platform because I want this to be resistant to the lab changing out the computer that manages it.

Experiments can have variable start and end times, and if there is an existing experiment running, the management of instructions still has to happen. This way if X starts their experiment yesterday, Y starting their experiment today shouldn't cause race conditions, and if X's expeiment ends before Y, Y's ongoing experiment shouldn't be interrupted.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have heard that opening a subprocess is an antipattern, but I don't know if there is a better way to do this." It's not possible to answer this - or really anything else in the question - without understanding: what **problem do you hope to solve** by using subprocesses? **Why not** do it some other way? Is it only because you can't think of another way? (Hint: why did you not need to start a subprocess, in order to use all the standard library modules? How did you use them?)

Comment: Basically a lab computer has to communicate with a piece of equipment. This involves sending commands that can overwrite each other, and also doing logic to figure out the best commands. A's main job is to read in data from these directories (mostly configuration files) and figures out the logic and packages them into serial instructions to avoid overwriting important instructions. 

Because my lab is full of non-coders, I want the command to be very simple. I hope to have a single command that pushes configurations to use, and also starts A if it hasn't been started yet.

Comment: "Because my lab is full of non-coders, I want the command to be very simple." - I can't understand - how will your students interact with the code? If they will not write any code themselves, then **why does it matter to them** how the code in `A.py` gets started? (What I am suggesting is, instead of using `subprocess` to run the `A.py` code as a separate process, why can't `B.py` just do `import A`, and perhaps call a function?)

Comment: Because experiments may have different end times. A needs to keep managing the logic if there are any existing experiments running. My colleagues (it's a research lab) may also kill their experiments if they notice a bad configuration, so they may ctrl-c to kill what's on their console.

Comment: Basically by moving files into D, I am telling A that I'm starting an experiment, and by removing files, I'm telling A I'm done with said experiment.

Comment: Okay, but will the students start the A process, and/or the B process? Or do they only add/remove files to the directory?

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I get it now. The students will run B; B wants to ensure that there is a "watchdog" A process running that monitors D, and then B will also write the file. Yes?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

They will start the B process. I want them to only ever use the B process.

What they will do is make a configuration file in a directory, and B will copy that file into a directory that is constant. A then periodically checks that directory for new configurations and if so, will add it to it's list of stuff to manage.